# How to restart some progress which is stopped by "ctrl+z"?

Tags: jobs, ctrl

When I am using

```
postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

to start the `postgresql` progress, I send a `ctrl+z` signal to stop it.
And now when I used `createuser` and `psql`, it has no response.

what can I do？

Answer (score 72, accepted):

After you press `ctrl+z` it will pause execution of the current process and move it to the background. If you wish to start running it in the background, then type `bg` after pressing `ctrl-z`.

If you wish to have it run in the foreground (and take away your ability to enter new commands into the prompt), type `fg` after pressing `ctrl-z`

If you wish to run it in the background right from the beginning use `&` at the end of your command.

```
postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data &
```

Answer (score 139):

Type `fg` in your shell. This will resume your process

Comment: or `bg` to resume your process on the background

Answer (score 3):

If you send a process to background usning `ctrl-z` it will pause itself.

You can resume that using `bg` and it will stay running in background.

If this is not what you want then stop postgres and start it again, I would use `service postgres start` and `service postgres stop`.

If those ain't working try `/etc/init.d/postgres stop` and `/etc/init.d/postgres start`.